# Implementing windows 8 like tiles in a web page using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Alright, I have added two div's in my web page and added below jQuery, and every thing looks fine, when i move my mouse on to the tile it expands, but when the first div expands, the second div position changes. i want to freeze the second div and the expanded tile should be on top of the second div. please suggest.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#div1").css("background", "Red");
    $("#div2").css("background", "Blue");
    $("#div1").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            height: "+=30px",
            width: "+=30px"
        }, 50);
    });
    $("#div1").mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            height: "-=30px",
            width: "-=30px"
        }, 50);
    });
    $("#div2").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            height: "+=30px",
            width: "+=30px"
        }, 50);
    });
    $("#div2").mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            height: "-=30px",
            width: "-=30px"
        }, 50);
    });
});
```

Comment: use `$("#div1,#div2").mouseenter(` and  `$("#div1,#div2").mouseleave(` as you are using the same functionality and creating a long code.Or you can use http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: Yes, but this is just beginning, i am going to add links and separate behavior for both div's. Thanks